# Automorphism Tower for $\Bbb Z_4$, $\Bbb Z_3$, $\Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $G$ be a group. Now consider $\operatorname{Aut} G$ then $\operatorname{Aut} (\operatorname{Aut} G) = \operatorname{Aut}^2(G)$, then $\operatorname{Aut}(\operatorname{Aut}(\operatorname{Aut} G))=\operatorname{Aut}^3(G)$ and so on.
>
> Let $n$ be the least positive integer for which $\operatorname{Aut}^n (G)$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Aut}^{n+1}(G)$. Find the value of $n$ for the groups $\Bbb Z_4$, $\Bbb Z_3$, $\Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_2$ and  explain why it is so. Just use Automorphism in Group theory.

For $\Bbb Z_4$ I can send the generator $1$ of $\Bbb Z_4$ to $1$ or $3$. So Aut($\Bbb Z_4$)=$\Bbb Z_2$ . Again $Aut(\Bbb Z_2)=\Bbb Z_2$. So we are done. Similarly for $\Bbb Z_3$. Now what about $\Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_2$?

Comment: $\text{Aut}(\Bbb Z_2)$ is not $\Bbb Z_2$, nor is $\text{Aut}(\Bbb Z_3) \cong \Bbb Z_3$.

Comment: You mean $Aut^n(G)$, not $Aut(G^n)$, right?

Comment: Based on the title I came here expecting something about p-adic integers and was disappointed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess by $\mathbb{Z}_n$ ($n$-adic numbers) the author actually means $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ or short $\mathbb{Z}/n$ (the notation $\mathbb{Z}_n$ for this is common, but still wrong.)

One checks directly that every permutation of the non-zero elements of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is actually an automorphism. It follows $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) \cong S_3$. It is well-known that $\mathrm{Aut}(S_n) \cong S_n$ if $n \neq 6$.

Comment: Whether notation is correct is a matter of opinion, isn't it?

Comment: You will change your mind as soon as you read papers where $\mathbb{Z}_p$ *and* $\mathbb{Z}/p$ are used simultaneously.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Many students, and even a fair number of professional mathematicians, will probably never have call to use $p$-adics.  Having a much simpler and cleaner notation available is a useful thing a lot of the time.  ($C_n$ is just fine, obviously, but it tends to understate a lot of the arithmetic structure that one's interested in in the first place.)

Comment: @Martin, this just means that the notation was wrong for that paper! Notation does and should vary depending on the context.

Comment: No, mathematical notations for basic objects should be universal and not contradict with other notations. This is the whole idea behind notation. By the way, have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_group (section on notation)